# Check if certain string exist in my enum values without NoSuchElement Exception

Tags: scala, enums

I have the following code:

```
object Order extends Enumeration("asc", "desc") {
  type OrderType = Value
  val asc, desc = Value
  }
```

And i use it:

```
  val someStr:String = "someStr"
  val order = Order.withName(someStr)
```

This gives me the enum of the input string, but if i send string "asc1" i get Exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: None.get (ProductRequest.scala
```

My question is - Can i iterate the values and check if the strings exists? This way i can throw better detailed exception..

I was thinking i can iterate Order.values -> but could not find something useful

Thanks

Comment: The way you construct Enumeration is deprecated since 2.10.

Comment: Yes saw it and updated the code  according to the answer.. got rid of the warning plugin showed in the eclipse.. tnx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your could define your Enumeration as:

```
object Order extends Enumeration {
  type OrderType = Value
  val asc = Value("asc")
  val desc = Value("desc")

  def isOrderType(s: String) = values.exists(_.toString == s)
}
```

And use it:

```
Order.isOrderType("asc")  //> res0: Boolean = true
Order.isOrderType("foo")  //> res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: What should I do if the value is not a string? eg: val MISSING_PARTS: Value = Value(4)

Answer (score 6):

This seems to do the trick:

```
object EnumerationTypes extends App {
  object Order extends Enumeration {
    type OrderType = Value
    val asc = Value("asc")
    val desc = Value("desc")
    def valueOf(name: String) = this.values.find(_.toString == name)
  }
  println(Order.valueOf("asc")) // Some(asc)
  println(Order.valueOf("ascending")) // None
}
```

It returns None when the string is not valid instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks, valueOf is useful since it returns Option! haven't liked Scala that much yet, but learning to like it :-)